# Microsoft Outlook Add-in can't extract/pass data to a localhost server via Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to build an Outlook add-in for encrypting/decrypting emails. The Add-in itself uses a web app, which in turn uses Javascript.
I basically want to pass the unencrypted/encrypted email to a local server running python using GET/POST requests, perform some encryption/decryption on it in python, and then pass it back to Outlook Add-in.
The problem is that the Add-in just won't pass any data to the local server nor get something in return. I have tried to work with both Django and Flask with the same results. I also configured the local servers to use locally-generated certificates and keys with no improvement. I even tried routing the HTTP connection using ngrok, but none came of it.

[Server response to GET request on HTTP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEkXn.png)

[Server response to GET request on HTTPS using Werkzeug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZeVX5.png)

The code given below never returns "Here5" on item-status. Clearly the success snippet isn't being run.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "https://127.0.0.1:8000/getPost/hello/",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json', // added data type
            success: function (res) {
                $('#item-status').text("Here5");
                $('#item-message').text(res);
            }
        });
```

I've also added the required URLs in the App Domain part of the manifest file:

```
<AppDomain>https://127.0.0.1:8000/getPost/hello/</AppDomain>
```

The Add-in performs fine when running GET requests from other sites on the internet, like:
https://api.github.com/users
However, I just can't seem to run it on my local server. How do I solve this?

Edit: After some debugging, I've learned that XMLHttpRequest status is 0 and responseText is empty. I think it might have something to do with CORS. Am I correct in that assumption? If yes, then how do I disable Cross Origin for localhost in this particular case?

Thank You

Comment: Do you see any errors in the debug console? Could you also include Office build version, platform, and OS version that you are running?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT After some debugging, I've learned that XMLHttpRequest status (xhr.response) is 0 and xhr.responseText is empty. Am I on the right path here? I'm running Windows 10 Pro for Workstations (Version 20H2) on a 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor. I have a Microsoft Office 365 subscription and the product version is 2108 (Build 14326.20702). For the Add-in, I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: You can try to confirm if it's CORS.  The debug Console should have an error ""Access to XMLHttpRequest at <local host...> from origin '<your addin domain>' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".  Enabling CORS depends on your local server tools or setup, I suggest looking up "Enable CORS" for the tool you are using to build your local server.